# Find Xpath to an element depending on the value of another element in a table row

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I'm new to Xpath so if this doesn't contain all relevant information apologies & let me know what you need to solve it.

I am trying to find an Xpath to an "expand arrow" element which expands a row in a table.  The "expand arrow" element isn't unique so I would like to select it based on text contained in another element on the same row. The layout is as follows:

```html
<td id="__table2-rows-row10-col0">
    <div class="sapUiTableCellFlex">
        <span id="__table2-rows-row10-    treeicon" title="Expand Node" role="button">
        <div id="__hbox27-__clone101">
            <div id="__data70-__clone101">
            <div id="__data71-__clone101">
                <span id="__text47-__clone101" title="sys-admin">sys-admin</span>
```

I'd like to select the element with title = **"Expand Node"**

```html
<span id="__table2-rows-row10-    treeicon" title="Expand Node" role="button">
```

based on the element with title or text = **"sys-admin"**

```html
<span id="__text47-__clone101" title="sys-admin">sys-admin</span>
```

I've played around with various options but I can't seem to get it to work.  Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element with *title* as **Expand Node** with respect to the element with *title* or *text* as **sys-admin** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *xpath* and *title* attribute:

  ```
  "//span[@title='sys-admin']//ancestor::span[@title='Expand Node']"
  ```
- *xpath* and *text()* attribute:

  ```
  "//span[text()='sys-admin']//ancestor::span[@title='Expand Node']"
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  My apologies, the indentation in my original snippet was incorrect so I updated the original text.  I found a solution in the meantime and added it below.  Thanks again.

Comment: @RCS  Indentation of HTML doesn't matters when you can adjust the HTML for testing. My answer would still work as `ancestor` does considers `../../preceding-sibling` too.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got it to work using the following xpath:

```html
//span[@title='sys-admin']/../../preceding-sibling::span[@title='Expand Node']
```